# How can i write this update query into codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

query:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE sports SET status = 0 WHERE sport_id NOT IN (".$sport_id.") and user_id='".$user_id."'";
```

Comment: Version of codeigniter? $sport_id is array?

Comment: yes sport_id is array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it's works for you...

```
$this->db->where_not_in('sport_id', explode(",",$sport_id));
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->update("sports", array("status" => 0));
```

Comment: i try your code but it's give error like Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1,4,16,17' . UPDATE `sports` SET `status` = 0 WHERE `sport_id` NOT IN ('1,4,16,17') AND `user_id` = '30'

Comment: check now..You need to explode `$sport_id`